# Basic java program cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, arraylist, cannot-find-symbol

I need help with this basic program. My friend had given me most of this code but not the import statements. Towards the end where it says `list.add(finalCombined.get(counter3));` , it gives me an error. The error I get is

```
Cannot find Symbol 
Symbol: variable list
location: class ArrayUtils
```

I'm very confused at this. I added which import statements I think I need. Thank you

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.lang.String;

public class ArrayUtils {
    public void randomStrings(ArrayList<String> arrayList,int nbrOfStrings,int vowelCnt, int strSize){
        ArrayList <String> finalCombined = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList <String> finalCombined = new ArrayList();
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < nbrOfStrings; cnt++)
        {
            int cnt2 = 0;
            int gn, size, vowelUsed;
            Random n1 = new Random();
            size = 122-96;
            //char cs[] = new char[strSize];
            //String cs;
            //cs = "";
            ArrayList <Character> cs = new ArrayList();
            int counter = 0;
            vowelUsed = 0;

            while (counter < 1)
            {
                vowelUsed = n1.nextInt(vowelCnt + 1);
                if (vowelUsed == 0)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    counter = 2;
                }

            }

            while (cnt2 < (strSize - vowelUsed))
            {
                gn = n1.nextInt(size) + 97;

                if (gn == 97 | gn == 101 | gn == 105 | gn == 111 | gn == 117 | gn == 121)
                {
                }

                else
                {
                    cs.add((char)gn);
                    //cs += ((char)gn + "");
                    cnt2 ++;
                }
            }
            while (cnt2 < strSize)
            {
                gn = n1.nextInt(size) + 97;
                if (gn == 97 | gn == 101 | gn == 105 | gn == 111 | gn == 117 | gn == 121)
                {
                    cs.add((char)gn);
                    //cs += ((char)gn + "");
                    cnt2 ++;
                }
            }
            //int check;
            //check = list.add(cs[cnt]);
            Collections.shuffle(cs);

            String combined;
            combined = "";
            //System.out.println(cs);

            int counter2 = 0;
            while (counter2 < strSize)
            {
                combined += cs.get(counter2); 
                counter2 ++;
            }
            finalCombined.add(combined);
            counter2 = 0;
            combined = "";

        } // end # strings    

        for (int counter3 = 0; counter3 < nbrOfStrings; counter3++)
        {
            list.add(finalCombined.get(counter3));
        }

    } // end method
}
```

Comment: It's good practice to use `||` instead of `|` when you are writing something like `if (gn == 97 | gn == 101 | gn == ...`.

Answer (score 2):

```
list.add(finalCombined.get(counter3));
```

You haven't declared any variable named `list`, so this line can't pass compilation.

Perhaps you meant

```
arrayList.add(finalCombined.get(counter3));
```

since your `randomStrings` method has an argument called `arrayList` that you are not using at all.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to change `list` to `arrayList` in line

```
list.add(finalCombined.get(counter3));
```

because `list` is not declared any where in your code and `arrayList` has not been used.

Answer (score 0):

You have not define variable called `list`. However you have declared the array list `finalCombined` with same name twice. One variable name should be change as `list`. Also you have to call to method through `main` method as below.

```
new ArrayUtils().randomStrings(new ArrayList<String>(), 6, 3, 3);
```

I'm just wandering what is the purpose of parameter `arrayList` in the method `randomStrings`. There is no use of this list with in the method `randomStrings`.

**Your output looks like below:**

```
[aeo]
[aeo, yii]
[aeo, yii, isu]
[aeo, yii, isu, aea]
[aeo, yii, isu, aea, aaa]
[aeo, yii, isu, aea, aaa, iek]
```

Answer (score 0):

Always declare variables properly and wisely which helps your code to be more readable and understandable. It means you are actually reducing the stress on the compiler ;)

A small suggestion : use an IDE while coding which can help you in compile time errors like this. Moreover they are so friendly in suggesting solutions and optimising code as well..!